# Splitting DataFrame rows into multiple based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe `df1` that has a bunch of columns like so:

|  | val_1 | val_2 | start | end | val_3 | val_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 70 | 1/1/2020 | 3/4/2020 | 10 | 20 |
| 1 | 20 | 80 | 1/1/2020 | 3/6/2021 | 30 | 40 |
| 2 | 30 | 90 | 1/1/2020 | 6/4/2021 | 50 | 60 |
| 3 | 40 | 100 | 12/5/2020 | 7/4/2021 | 70 | 80 |
| 4 | 89 | 300 | 4/5/2020 | 6/8/2022 | 40 | 10 |

I need to iterate over the rows, and split the cross-year periods into continuous same year ones. The remaining values in the row need to stay the same and maintain their data types like so:

|  | val_1 | val_2 | start | end | val_3 | val_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 70 | 1/1/2020 | 3/4/2020 | 10 | 20 |
| 1 | 20 | 80 | 1/1/2020 | 12/31/2020 | 30 | 40 |
| 2 | 20 | 80 | 1/1/2021 | 3/6/2021 | 30 | 40 |
| 3 | 30 | 90 | 1/1/2020 | 12/31/2020 | 50 | 60 |
| 4 | 30 | 90 | 1/1/2021 | 6/4/2021 | 50 | 60 |
| 5 | 40 | 100 | 7/5/2021 | 11/17/2021 | 70 | 80 |
| 6 | 89 | 300 | 4/5/2020 | 12/31/2020 | 40 | 10 |
| 7 | 89 | 300 | 1/1/2021 | 12/31/2021 | 40 | 10 |
| 8 | 89 | 300 | 1/1/2021 | 6/8/2022 | 40 | 10 |

Is there a fast and efficient way to do this? I tried iterating over the rows and doing it but I'm having trouble with the indices and appending rows after an index. Also, people have said that's probably not the best idea to edit things that I'm iterating over so I was wondering if there is a better way to do it. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you!

**EDIT**

If the row spans more than a year, that should break into 3 or more rows, accordingly. I've edited the tables to accurately reflect this. Thank you!

Comment: what happened to `12/5/2020 ` for the `start` column?

Comment: Made a mistake. Value for the last row of the start column is `12/5/2020` and **NOT** `3/5/2021`. Thank you for pointing that out. Sorry about that!

Comment: You've made another typo... in the final result. Row 3 from `df1` once again disappears, and row 5 in the output comes out of nowhere.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different approach. Note that I've already converted `start` and `end` to datetimes, and I didn't bother sorting the resultant DataFrame because I didn't want to assume a specific ordering for your use-case.

```py
import pandas as pd


def jump_to_new_year(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df["start"] = df["start"].map(lambda t: pd.Timestamp(t.year + 1, 1, 1))
    return df


def fill_to_year_end(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df["end"] = df["start"].map(lambda t: pd.Timestamp(t.year, 12, 31))
    return df


def roll_over(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    mask = df.start.dt.year != df.end.dt.year
    if all(~mask):
        return df
    start_df = fill_to_year_end(df[mask].copy())
    end_df = roll_over(jump_to_new_year(df[mask].copy()))
    return pd.concat([df[~mask], start_df, end_df]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

This is a recursive function. It first checks if any start-end date pairs have mismatched years. If not, we simply return the DataFrame. If so, we fill to the end of the year in the `start_df` DataFrame. Then we jump to the new year and fill that to the `end` date in the `end_df` DataFrame. Then we recurse on `end_df`, which will be a smaller subset of the original input.

**Warning:** this solution assumes that all start dates occur *on or before* the end date's year. If you start in 2020 and end in 2019, you will recurse infinitely and blow the stack.

Demo:

```py
>>> df
   val_1  val_2      start        end  val_3  val_4
0     10     70 2020-01-01 2020-03-04     10     20
1     20     80 2020-01-01 2021-03-06     30     40
2     30     90 2020-01-01 2021-06-04     50     60
3     40    100 2020-12-05 2021-07-04     70     80
4     89    300 2020-04-05 2022-06-08     40     10

>>> roll_over(df)
   val_1  val_2      start        end  val_3  val_4
0     10     70 2020-01-01 2020-03-04     10     20
1     20     80 2020-01-01 2020-12-31     30     40
2     30     90 2020-01-01 2020-12-31     50     60
3     40    100 2020-12-05 2020-12-31     70     80
4     89    300 2020-04-05 2020-12-31     40     10
5     20     80 2021-01-01 2021-03-06     30     40
6     30     90 2021-01-01 2021-06-04     50     60
7     40    100 2021-01-01 2021-07-04     70     80
8     89    300 2021-01-01 2021-12-31     40     10
9     89    300 2022-01-01 2022-06-08     40     10

# An example of reordering the DataFrame
>>> roll_over(df).sort_values(by=["val_1", "start"])
   val_1  val_2      start        end  val_3  val_4
0     10     70 2020-01-01 2020-03-04     10     20
1     20     80 2020-01-01 2020-12-31     30     40
5     20     80 2021-01-01 2021-03-06     30     40
2     30     90 2020-01-01 2020-12-31     50     60
6     30     90 2021-01-01 2021-06-04     50     60
3     40    100 2020-12-05 2020-12-31     70     80
7     40    100 2021-01-01 2021-07-04     70     80
4     89    300 2020-04-05 2020-12-31     40     10
8     89    300 2021-01-01 2021-12-31     40     10
9     89    300 2022-01-01 2022-06-08     40     10
```

Comment: This solution more accurately reflects what I would like to achieve. Thank you!
Ben is right, I'm afraid. If the solution spans more than a year, then they should correspondingly break into a single year period at most. I've edited the question to reflect this as well.

Comment: @karanrajpal14 hang tight. Working on a modification.

Comment: @karanrajpal14 wow that was terrible timing with the site maintenance. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Find the year end after `date_range`, then `explode`

```
df['end'] = [[y]+pd.date_range(x,y)[pd.date_range(x,y).is_year_end].strftime('%m/%d/%y').tolist() for x , y in zip(df['start'],df['end'])]
df = df.explode('end')
df
Out[29]: 
   val_1  val_2      start       end  val_3  val_4
0     10     70   1/1/2020  3/4/2020     10     20
1     20     80   1/1/2020  3/6/2021     30     40
1     20     80   1/1/2020  12/31/20     30     40
2     30     90   1/1/2020  6/4/2021     50     60
2     30     90   1/1/2020  12/31/20     50     60
3     40    100  12/5/2020  7/4/2021     70     80
3     40    100  12/5/2020  12/31/20     70     80
```

Update

```
df.end=pd.to_datetime(df.end)
df.start=pd.to_datetime(df.start)
df['Newstart'] = [list(set([x]+pd.date_range(x,y)[pd.date_range(x,y).is_year_start].tolist()))
                  for x , y in zip(df['start'],df['end'])]
df['Newend'] = [[y]+pd.date_range(x,y)[pd.date_range(x,y).is_year_end].tolist()
                  for x , y in zip(df['start'],df['end'])]

out = df.explode(['Newend','Newstart'])
val_1  val_2      start        end  val_3  val_4   Newstart     Newend
0     10     70 2020-01-01 2020-03-04     10     20 2020-01-01 2020-03-04
1     20     80 2020-01-01 2021-03-06     30     40 2021-01-01 2021-03-06
1     20     80 2020-01-01 2021-03-06     30     40 2020-01-01 2020-12-31
2     30     90 2020-01-01 2021-06-04     50     60 2021-01-01 2021-06-04
2     30     90 2020-01-01 2021-06-04     50     60 2020-01-01 2020-12-31
3     40    100 2020-12-05 2021-07-04     70     80 2021-01-01 2021-07-04
3     40    100 2020-12-05 2021-07-04     70     80 2020-12-05 2020-12-31
4     89    300 2020-04-05 2022-06-08     40     10 2020-04-05 2022-06-08
4     89    300 2020-04-05 2022-06-08     40     10 2022-01-01 2020-12-31
4     89    300 2020-04-05 2022-06-08     40     10 2021-01-01 2021-12-31
```

Comment: @ddejohn noticed that as well , since the op's input dose not match his output  :-)

Comment: Yeah, looking more closely this isn't matching OP's desired output at all (despite their apparent typo).

Comment: Sorry about the typo. I've added the clarification in the comment above.
Thank you, BENY!
While this definitely is smart, I was looking for a way to update the start date accordingly as well and it looks like this method doesn't achieve that. Do you have any other suggestions in mind regarding that?

Comment: @karanrajpal14 check the update , now you have the column new end and new start ~

Comment: @ddejohn check the update

Comment: @Ben.T check the update ~